# Once users become admins they can no longer sign in (sessions aren't created)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, admin

I started having problems with admins "Signing in" on some of my apps. I have no idea why. I started a new app from scratch to try and see why this might be happening. Even in the new app it happened. The only app of mine which allows admins to sign in is the oldest app I have, and I cross examined the controllers, helpers, models and even the views, just to check the differences between the one app that allows admins to sign in and the others that don't. There are no differences.

Anyone got any ideas why?

I create a user - works perfectly. I can sign in and out as many times as I please. I toggle the user admin, and then I can not longer sign in anymore. It just redirects to the sign in page, which means that the session failed. I think it is a problem with password encryption - but honestly don't have a clue.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 include SessionsHelper
  protect_from_forgery
end



class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @title = "Sign in"
      end

      def create
        user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                                 params[:session][:password])
        if user.nil?
          flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
          @title = "Sign in"
          render 'new'
        else
          sign_in user
          redirect_back_or user
        end
      end

        def destroy
        sign_out
        redirect_to root_path
      end

    end



class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
before_filter :admin_user,   :only => [:index, :destroy]

  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end


  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
end

    def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
    def edit
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

   def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

   private



    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
     def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
  end


module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end
    def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

    def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

    def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end

   def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

   def deny_access
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    clear_return_to
  end

  private

    def user_from_remember_token
      User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
    end
     def store_location
      session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    end

    def clear_return_to
      session[:return_to] = nil
    end
end



module UsersHelper
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { :size => 50 })
    gravatar_image_tag(user.email.downcase, :alt => user.name,
                                            :class => 'gravatar',
                                            :gravatar => options)
  end
end



require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :investments, :dependent => :destroy

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :password, :presence     => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length       => { :within => 6..40 }


   before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end

    def feed
    # This is preliminary. See Chapter 12 for the full implementation.
    Investment.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end


  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end
end

#routes
resources :users
 resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]



  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'


root :to => "pages#home"


#Gems

Using rake (0.9.2) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.9) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.9) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.3) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.29) 
Using actionpack (3.0.9) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.19) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.9) 
Using arel (2.0.10) 
Using activerecord (3.0.9) 
Using activeresource (3.0.9) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using rdoc (3.8) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.9) 
Using rails (3.0.9) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.3)
```

As you can see, exactly the same as the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. And my other app that actually works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was simple. As soon as I asked the question, I relaxed and waited for help from stackoverflow, right then I had an idea.

When you 'toggle' a user 'admin', you should do the following:

```
$ rails console
>> user = User.first
>> user.admin?
=> false
>> user.password = "foobar"
>> user.toggle!(:admin)
=> true
>> user.admin?
=> true
```

Taken from [the Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users)

Its important to put in the password. I had forgotten to do this because I was trying to learn the process without looking at the tutorial every time, and forgot the password part. So just as I supected, I could log into my admin accounts without a password, then go to edit user and change the password back to what it was.